# MySQL: Selecting where only one unique Max record exists

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

My data is:

```
bid_id,  fkp_id, fkb_id, bid_amount
1  ,        13 ,   1 ,  22000  
2 ,         13 ,   2 ,  23000  
3 ,         13 ,   2 ,  23000 
4,          3  ,   1 ,  5000
5,          3  ,   2 ,  6000
```

If there is a tie (in this case bid_id 2 and bid_id 3) this record should not be selected and only unique max bid_amount value record should be selected.

in this case desired record is bid_id 1 and bid_id 5

Comment: is your desired output result is only bid 1

Comment: What is your expected output?  Have you written any code yet?

Comment: @ankit agrawal yes in this case

Comment: Obviously it gives
2 , 13 , 2 , 23000 as output.As Max amount is 23000 and MySql make default indexing from top to bottom,and its gives 2 bid_Id record as output.

Comment: @SagarGangwal: NO! ... Still no.

Comment: before this i used group_by and order by but did not work

Comment: add your desired output

Comment: Desired record is bid_id. Oh good.

Comment: _**@shabirullah**_: Are you expecting multiple results on same max `bid_amount` value? Or if various combinations of `fkp_id` and `fkb_id` have same max `bid_amount` value, which one are you expecting in result?

Comment: @RavinderReddy: in this case bid_id 1 is unique so i want only unique max bid_amount but if there is tie ( in this case bid_id 2 and bid_id3) all records should be discarded if they have tie. if no tie than max bid_amount should be selected among remaining records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to your data if you need  all with one unique max amount 
and the max amount is related  to  the amount itself you could use

```
  select bid_id, fkp_id, fkb_id, bid_amount
  from table_name 
  where bid_amount = (  select max(t.bid_amount)
          from ( select bid_amount, count(*)
                from table_name
                group by bid_amount
                having count(*) = 1 ) t )
```

If your unique max amount  is for flp_id   then you shoulf group by properly for this columns too

```
select bid_id, fkp_id, fkb_id, bid_amount
from table_name 
where ( fkp_id, bid_amount)  in  (  select  t.fkp_id, max(t.bid_amount)
        from ( select fkp_id, bid_amount, count(*)
              from table_name
              group by fkp_id, bid_amount
              having count(*) = 1 ) t 
         group by t.fkp_id )
```

Comment: @scaisEdge error 1248 every table should have their own alias

Comment: @shabirullah  ... correct  .. missing table name for diamica temp table  ... answer  updated

Comment: i add another entry i think the question is improve. 13 and 3 are products and i want to fetch these two rows but with unique max bid_amount value

Comment: @shabirullah  .  changin the terms of the question is not fair .. -- soy your max amount is not absolute but is for fkp_id ??    aniway i have update the answer

Comment: yes it is for fkp_id and fkp_id should not be repeated(13,13 ,3,3) wrong i need (13, 4) records

Comment: my desired result is bid_id 1 and bid_id 5.

Comment: i am still working on the same problem but did not find solution. have you received my last comment  that i want bid_id 1 and bid_id 5

Comment: and with my asnwer  what you get .? . please commnet  me the actual result

Comment: 100% accurate and desired result